# How do I retrieve a versions at a certain versions with Paper Trails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, paper-trail-gem

I'm working on switching from vestal_version to paper_trail.
I know vestal versions use versions number while paper_trails use timestamps.

`paper_trails` has a method called `version_at(timestamp)`, but I found a lot of versions in my table with the same exact date so that method will not work as expected.

I need to achieve the following.

```
widget1 = widget.paper_trail.version(4)
widget2 = widget.paper_trail.version(10)
# there are a couple of way to get the diff 
# using active record diff ( I prefer this to Jeremy Weiskotten's PaperTrail)
changes = widget1.diff(widget2)
# I know I can do 
versions = widget.versions[4]  
# that only returns versions model instead of widget
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to do `reify` to get the widget object

```
widget.versions[4].reify
```

Find documentation and examples [here](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#1c-basic-usage)